# Nexus Stock Experience on Galaxy S5

Tags: stock-android, samsung-galaxy-s-5, stock-rom

Is it possible to get a Nexus Stock experience of Android 5.0 (5.0.1) on the Samsung Galaxy S5? I realise this doesn't exist officially/I would have to use a custom ROM or build it myself.

So does such a ROM (Pure Nexus Stock) exist for the S5? If not are the components required available in the public domain? I assume this would be the relevant kernel files, radio, device drivers etc? Would it need to be rooted or is it possible to just unlock the bootloader without rooting as on Nexus devices?

Comment: Try cyanogenmod. It's probably as close to stock as you'll be able to get. I don't know if it came out though.

Comment: Well, there's no reason of asking such question any more as you will be getting the Android Lollipop update, maybe by the end of this december you will be part of Lollipop family, there is a post over [techtimes](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/21456/20141207/samsung-galaxy-s5-galaxy-note-4-and-lg-g3-android-5-0-lolipop-software-update-release-schedule-leaks.htm) French mobile carrier club SFR has released the dates when Lollipop will be pushed out, it do has a [english version too](http://www.rapidsofttechnologies.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/android-uppates.jpg)

Comment: @Samsung - Yeah I thought that might end up being the only answer. Will go with that if I can't find another way but I'd really prefer Nexus Stock. Also I don't think CyanogenMod based on 5.0 is stable yet?

Comment: @Peter Carlos - I know lollipop will be released soon but I'm specifically after Stock Lollipop not the Samsung TouchWiz version. Since a Google Play Edition seems to be forever delayed I'm not hopefully this will be released soon...

Comment: Well @db579 I am afraid in that case I don't think we are going to see that happen in near future !

Comment: Cyanogenmod or some other custom ROM is the only way to go right now. Once the S5 GPE gets released someone will probably modify it to work on your device. They can't just be cross flashed afaik (the S4 certainly couldn't despite identical hardware). Note: The S4/S5 google play devices are not fully 'stock' they have a small bit of TouchWiz in there to allow the S-View cover, and the drivers etc are all modified by Samsung obviously. Also installing custom ROMs may well invalidate your carrier and manufacturer warranty.

Comment: Out of interest why couldn't it be reflashed if it's the same hardware? Different bootloader?